# Relation between higher CPU frequency and thrashing?

Tags: cpu, frequency

This happened to be one of my class test question. 
In a demand paging system, the CPU utilization is 20% and the paging disk utilization is 97.7%
If the CPU speed is increased, will the CPU usage be increased in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paging is effectively a bottleneck in this example. The amount of computation per unit time might increase slightly with a faster CPU but not in proportion to the increase in CPU speed (so the percentage utilization would decrease).

A quick and dirty estimation would use Amdahl's Law. In the example, 80% of the work is paging and 20% is CPU-limited, so an N-fold improvement in CPU performance would result in a speedup factor of 1/((1 - 0.2) + (0.2/N)).

A more realistic estimate would add an awareness of queueing theory to recognize that if the paging requests came in more frequently the utilization would actually increase even with a fixed buffer size. However, the increase in paging utilization is smaller than the increase in request frequency.

Without looking at the details of queueing theory, one can also simply see that the maximum potential improvement in paging is just over 2%. (If paging utilization was driven up to 100%: 100/97.7 or 1.0235.) Even at 100% paging utilization, paging would take 0.80/(100/97.7) of the original time, so clearly there is not much opportunity for improvement.

If a 10-fold CPU speed improvement drove paging utilization to effectively 100%, every second of work under the original system would use 781.6 milliseconds in paging (800 ms / (100/97.7)) and 20 milliseconds in the CPU (200 ms / 10). CPU utilization would decrease to 20 / (781.6 + 20) or about 2.5%.